# What term is used for a person who prefers to communicate in writing as opposed to speaking?

Tags: letter-writing

This is my first post, so please forgive me if my question has already been answered. I looked through the list quickly, but didn't see anything similar.

Comment: Verba volant,  scripta manent : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verba_volant,_scripta_manent

Comment: Without looking up anything either, I'll go ahead and offer the German-y compound *textlover* and the Grecian *graphophile* for normal preferences and the Latiny *scriptomaniac* for people who overdo it.

Comment: Those are explicitly text-related. Generally speaking, the term for "a person who prefers to communicate in writing as opposed to via a phone call" is *anyone under 40*.

Comment: For clarification, are you imagining someone who would prefer sitting in a chat room rather than speaking face to face? Or, is it someone who lacks any confidence in their public speaking ability?

Comment: No. I'm referring to a business professional who is generally well understood and often praised for their written communications but who finds it difficult to express the same thoughts orally.

Comment: "written communicator" would get the point across quickly

Comment: Tongue-tied ... introvert ... nerd ... nerdy ... dork ....